# Pandas keep first one of duplicate alternating values in a group

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I have a df looks like this. What I want to do is to keep the first one of each repeating Order_Side within a group. So I would want to remove index 5,8 since it's repeating and index 20, 26. The Order_Side should be alternating like 1 Buy and 1 Sell within each **Var1 Group**

I read similar question on stackoverflow and tried

`df.loc[df['Order_Side'] != df['Order_Side'].shift()]`

This will give me

[image]

Altough this keeps alternating Sell and Buy and Keeps the first one of repeating value. But it is not within each **Var1 GROUP**

Because I only need the Sell and Buy to alternate within each Var1 group but not between different groups. When crossing groups, this needs to be reset.

Please take a look at index 28 and 34 in the first picture. 34 should be Kept because it's a different group now. It's 8 rather than 7. So it should not be bounded by the alternating requirement. Then within the 8 group, it needs to be alternating again.

Comment: `sort_values` + `drop_duplicates`https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can introduce another condition that allows any row which has a different Var1 group from the previous row.

```
cond1 = df['Order_Side'] != df['Order_Side'].shift()
cond2 = df['Var1'] != df['Var1'].shift()
df.loc[cond1 | cond2]
```